# FUNCTION databasename.SHA2 does not exist

Tags: mysql, hash

I am hosting my domain on goddady and am trying to hash the passwords in the database. However, it throws the error:

```
MySQL said: 

#1305 - FUNCTION dbname.SHA2 does not exist
```

This is the command I'm using to insert the data in the db.

```
insert into `dbname`.`tbl_members` values ('1', 'admin', SHA2('password', 224));
```

This works perfectly fine when I execute it on my local server.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's probably a [version problem.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html#function_sha2)

> SHA2() was added in MySQL 5.5.5.