# How to UPDATE field to include hashes for password

Tags: mysql, sql, database, hash

At the moment I have a database field which stores passwords like this:

```
TeacherPassword

j.lu01
pesci02
cricket01
```

But I want to change the password field so that each row contains hashes for each password. But how can this be done because I tried an update like below but it did not work:

```
UPDATE Teacher
SET SHA2 TeacherPassword
```

I am using sql in phpmyadmin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL has a `SHA1()` function

```
UPDATE Teacher
SET SHA1(TeacherPassword)
```

Or even [`Password()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/password-hashing.html)

```
UPDATE Teacher
SET Password(TeacherPassword)
```

[Encryption](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html) functions in MySQL

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE Teacher
SET password = SHA2(TeacherPassword,512);
```

Comment: I get an error stating `#1305 - FUNCTION mobile_app.SHA2 does not exist`, I am using phpmyadmin

Comment: [Version Problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5596238/function-databasename-sha2-does-not-exist)